# Java JTextField Warning Issues

Tags: java, try-catch, warnings, jtextfield

I am making a java welcome GUI. The user enters his first name, last name, age, sex, and it will display back to him. I set up warnings if the user does not enter the fields except for the first name and last name. It does warnings for age, state, and sex but skips the warnings for the name and goes for the try/catch. I don't understand why is it doing that and how can I fix it to display that warning?

```
buttonWelcome.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pressing) {

            int userAge;

            // a try/catch to catch any error and display
            // back to the user that he must finish
            try {

                String first = firstname.getText();
                String last = lastname.getText();
                Object state = stateBox.getSelectedItem();
                userAge = Integer.parseInt(age.getText());
                boolean male = maleButton.isSelected();
                boolean female = femaleButton.isSelected();

                // warning section

                if (firstname.getText().trim().equals("")) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Must enter first name");

                } else if (lastname.getText().trim().equals("")) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Must enter last name");

                } else if (userAge <= 0) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Must be a positive age");

                } else if (stateBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {

                    JOptionPane
                            .showMessageDialog(null, "Must select state");

                } else if (buttonGenders.isSelected(null)) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Must select gender");

                }

                if (male) {

                    textArea.setText("Welcome Male " + first + ", " + last
                            + " of " + userAge + " years old from " + state);

                } else if (female) {

                    textArea.setText("Welcome Female " + first + ", "
                            + last + " of " + userAge + " years old from "
                            + state);

                }

                // display back the error as a pop up
            } catch (Exception e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Must Complete your Info");

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Log the stacktrace of the exception to see whats wrong.

Comment: how do you do that in eclipse?

Comment: Add `e.printStacktrace()` before `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Must Complete your Info");` or use the debugger

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses